# Android add custom search bar in application

Tags: android, sqlite, uisearchbar

I want to implement search bar in my application which will filter list view depending on letters entered in edit text. Here is what I have actually like a design

[image]

So I want to filter the elements by title so I guess I have to change the sqlite statement, because I'm populating the listview from database.

And I have two question :

1.Which is the best way to implement custom search bar : add textwatcher to an edit text and change the sqlite statement everytime user enter letter or ?

2.How to sort in sqlite depending on letters entered from user. If user press A I want to show all items which have that letter no matter if it's in the beginning or in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the things to achieve this are very simple, no matter what kind of `Adapter` are you using. First you need to create `TextWatcher` and add it to your `Edit Text`. Than in your `onAfterTextChanged()` you can create your new SQL statement like :

```
String sql = "SELECT title FROM cards WHERE title LIKE '%"+someString+"%'"
//where someString is `Charsequence` which you get in your onAfterTextChanged()
```

Before getting your data again if you are using `ArrayList` or any other kind of `Lists` for storing your data you have to clear them, so you can get the new data. And than you can simply call `adapter.notifySetDataChanged()`. And it should work. At least this is the way how I'm doing this. Maybe it's not the best way, but it's working.

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of your database? if it is not a BIG one then i think the simple SQL should work for you:

```
SELECT  Column1, Column2
FROM    myTable
WHERE   myColumn LIKE 'somecharacter%'
```

You can call to DB while the user is typing or can use some other logic like when the user press a specific button.