# Android filter listview depending on edittext input with sql statements

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, filtering

I want to ask a little question. I want to know which is the best way I can filter my list view which I am populating from sqlite database and I want to filter it depending on users entered letters in edit text. I'm not showing any code because I have only sqlite statements and that's it. I have to change the sqlite statement which I'm using to populate the database.

So my question is, how can I change my sqlite statement when user entered letters in edit text, and how can I update my listview with the new data filtered with the new sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the answer to your previous question, they are very similar : [search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848100/android-add-custom-search-bar-in-application/8891185#8891185)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it as follows:

```
//Search text and changed handler
        EditText tbSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.android_searchbox);
        tbSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                ListView av = getListView();
                SimpleCursorAdapter filterAdapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter)av.getAdapter();
                filterAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        entries.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return mDbHelper.fetchAllEntries(constraint);
            }
        });
```

With this approach you will need a method similar to FetchAllEntries(string sFilter)

```
/*
 * Override to return a Cursor over the list of Entries filtered by a
 * constraint
 * 
 * @return Cursor over filtered Entries
 */
public Cursor fetchAllEntries(CharSequence constraint) {

    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
        // Return the full list
        return fetchAllEntries();
    } else {

        String value = "%" + constraint.toString() + "%";

        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_BODY, KEY_USER_PROFICIENCY };

        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns,
                KEY_TITLE + " like ? OR " + KEY_BODY + " like ? ", new String[] { value, value }, null, null,
                KEY_TITLE + " ASC ");

    }
}
```

Here I have a table with two columns (title, body)

Comment: Any ideas how can I make this working with BaseAdapter. Because the adapter I'm using is an implementation of lazy loading and it extends BaseAdapter.

Comment: hmm.. sorry I donT know much about adapter types but based on [what I read](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html), that s what SimpleCursorAdapter is created for. To work with a database directly..